# Arrays of Pthreads

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am trying to multiply two matrices using pthreads. For each element in the matrices, a separate pthread is to be created. In my program, I do that, but use an array of pthread_t, dynamically declared to be the size of the total number of elements in the two matrices.

The problem I am having is that I create the threads just fine, but as a test in my runner function, I have a cout statement that does not seem to execute even once. For the sake of brevity, I removed the part of the code that reads the two matrices from file and stores them into two arrays. It also counted the number of elements in the two matrices and used it to set the size of the pthread array. I have tested that code separately, so I'm pretty sure that it has nothing to do with my problem.

Here is the code pertaining to my problem:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_t *workers;
workers = new pthread_t[numThreads];
int counter = 0;
for(int count1 = 0; count1 < (rows2 * cols2); count1++)
{
    infile2 >> array2[count1];
}
for(int i = 0; i < rows1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < cols1; j++)
    {
        location *data = new location;
        data->row = i;
        data->col = j;
        pthread_create(&(workers[counter]), &attr, runner, data);
        counter++;
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < rows2; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < cols2; j++)
    {
        location *data = new location;
        data->row = i;
        data->col = j;
        pthread_create(&(workers[counter]), &attr, runner, data);
        counter++;
    }
}
for(int add = 0; add < 24; add++)
{
    pthread_join(workers[add], NULL);
}
return 0;
}
```

and my runner function:

```
void *runner(void *param)
{
    cout << "bob" << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you initialize `pthread_attr` anywhere in your real code? If not use `pthread_attr_init()` or pass it as NULL if you aren't using it.  It looks like `pthread_create` is failing with "invalid argument".  Also if you are not already doing so in your real code, check all your return codes.  Pthread arguments return 0 on success and a positive integer on failure.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. I changed the part where i pass attr to the function to NULL and the cout statement worked.